# Using URLConnection and OutputStreamReader inside a Service

Tags: android, service, null, outputstream, urlconnection

I am trying to use URLConnection and OutputStreamWriter, to send data to a php file on localhost, inside of a Service. The project builds without any errors but when I run the app no data is sent to the server. The try block is returning a null exception.

```
public void onCreate() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Service Created", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        WifiManager wifi = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
        wifi.setWifiEnabled(true);
}
    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startid) {
        WifiManager wifi = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
        if(wifi != null && wifi.isWifiEnabled()) {
            //The code
            rssi = wifi.getConnectionInfo().getRssi(); 
            name = wifi.getConnectionInfo().getSSID(); 
            addr = wifi.getConnectionInfo().getBSSID(); 
            level = WifiManager.calculateSignalLevel(rssi, 100);  
            percentage = (int) ((level / 100.0) * 100);
            pc=Integer.toString(percentage);
        }
        Toast.makeText(this, "Service Started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        try {
            link = "http://192.168.0.8:80/clubsol.php";
            data = URLEncoder.encode("name", "UTF-8") + "=" +
                    URLEncoder.encode(name, "UTF-8");
            data += "&" + URLEncoder.encode("mac", "UTF-8") + "=" +
                    URLEncoder.encode(addr, "UTF-8");
            data += "&" + URLEncoder.encode("percentage", "UTF-8") + "=" +
                    URLEncoder.encode(pc, "UTF-8");
            URL url = new URL(link);
            URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
            conn.setDoOutput(true);
            OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
            wr.write(data);
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("Exception: " + e.getMessage());
            Toast.makeText(this, "Exception: " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Service Stopped", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
```

Comment: can you post the stacktrace ?

Comment: A null exception? What is that?

Comment: You cannot use Toast() and internet code like that for urlconnection in the same thread.

Comment: @greenapps Any code changes that you suggest ? I'm new to Android

Comment: @greenapps "Exception: null" I am getting this toast

Comment: Why do you fail to tell us that `e.getMessage()` returns null?

Comment: You will have nice exceptions mentioned in the logcat. Which you failed to post here.